# Missing Installation File

Tags: system-installation

When I try to install Kubuntu 15.04-desktop-i386 to an empty SSD on my computer from a iso on DVD, it seems to go all the way through but then shows an error message:  Could not retrieve the required installation files.  When I check the error log, I find "does not contain D:\casper\vmlinuz."  I'm stuck!

Comment: How did you try to install?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: To add to Pilot6's excellent advice, did you verify the checksum? Look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) -- it's not as complicated as it looks, just follow the directions if you've not already done so.